# Make post request on GameMaker

Tags: game-maker

I'am new to game maker, and now creating a very simple application, which should get some data from web server (in JSON), and display in special way on device. GameMaker looks to be useful to create this kind of cross-platfrom applications, but it is very difficult for me to find a good samples.

I need to make post request with two name-value pairs ("data", and "info"), and parse result from JSON.

Maybe, someone have a sample, how to do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If use GM Studio, use `http_post_string`, for other versions you have to use extensions.